# How to send in Akka from outside of an actor and still be able to use sender

Tags: scala, akka, implicit

I'm new in Scala and Akka. I'm finishing reactive programming course at Coursera and I decide to do some refactoring during this refactoring I discovered that my code does not working because of behavior which affects below code:

```
package common

import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props, Actor}
import akka.event.LoggingReceive

object NotWorkingActorApp extends App {

case class Start()
case class FromOuter()
case class FromInner()

class InnerProxy {
    def sendInner(innerParam: ActorRef): Unit = {
        innerParam.!(FromOuter)
    }
}

class Outer extends Actor {

    var inner = context.system.actorOf(Props[Inner], name = "inner")
    var proxy = new InnerProxy

    def receive = LoggingReceive {
        case Start => proxy.sendInner(inner)
        case FromInner => println("Finish!")
    }
}

class Inner extends Actor {
    def receive = LoggingReceive {
        case FromOuter => sender.!(FromInner)
    }
}

val system = ActorSystem("InnerOuterSystem")
val outer = system.actorOf(Props[Outer], name = "outer")
outer.!(Start)

}
```

Logs after running this part of code are like below:

```
[DEBUG] [08/25/2014 23:37:14.255] [main] [EventStream(akka://InnerOuterSystem)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
[DEBUG] [08/25/2014 23:37:14.257] [main] [EventStream(akka://InnerOuterSystem)] Default Loggers started
[DEBUG] [08/25/2014 23:37:14.282] [InnerOuterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://InnerOuterSystem/user/outer] received handled message Start
[DEBUG] [08/25/2014 23:37:14.284] [InnerOuterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://InnerOuterSystem/user/inner] received handled message FromOuter
[INFO] [08/25/2014 23:37:14.304] [InnerOuterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://InnerOuterSystem/deadLetters] Message [common.NotWorkingActorApp$FromInner$] from Actor[akka://InnerOuterSystem/user/inner#-2100738560] to Actor[akka://InnerOuterSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

So it looks like inner cannot see its sender. Everything works if method "sendInner" is in Outer class but I wanna have InnerProxy class and wanna use it because I like to have well modularized code. How should I do it?

Below versions:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2.3",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.2.3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to solve this issue is to redefine `InnerProxy` like so:

```
class InnerProxy {
    def sendInner(innerParam: ActorRef)(implicit senderRef:ActorRef): Unit = {
        innerParam ! FromOuter
    }
}
```

As long as you are calling `sendInner` from inside of an actor instance then you always have an implicit `ActorRef` available as `self`.  The result is that actor making the call to `sendInner` will end up as the `sender` in whatever actor receives the message and can then be replied to.